# pagination using bootpag an Bootstrap functionality

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootpag pagination to support pagination in my application

```
<div id="demo">
    <?php //print_r($data);?>
</div>
<div id="page-selection"></div>

$('#page-selection').bootpag({
total: <?=$totalRows?>
}).on("page", function(event, /* page number here */ num)
{
    $("#demo").html("Insert content"); // some ajax content loading...  
});
```

Pagination is working but same rows are displaying in all the page, I want to set five rows per page and remaining rows should display in next page, how to i set the number of rows per page using bootpag?

Comment: Can you show us your PHP code?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the problem is. Is it that it shows the right amount of page numbers, but clicking on a new page number doesn't actually change the content?

Comment: yes,i need to set the number of rows to be displayed per page how to set it